# Insert statment created by django ORM at bulk_create

Tags: python, django, orm

I am kind of new to python and django.

I am using `bulk_create` to insert a lot of rows and as a former DBA I would very much like to see what insert statments are being executed. I know that for querys you can use `.query` but for insert statments I can't find a command.

Is there something I'm missing or is there no easy way to see it? (A regular print is fine by me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to set `DEBUG = True` and check `connection.queries` after executing the query. This stores the raw queries and the time each query takes.

```
from django.db import connection


MyModel.objects.bulk_create(...)
print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
```

There's more information [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

A great tool to make this information easily accessible is the [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar).

Comment: Thank you very much! it gave me even more than I needed!